# Anybody have any experience trying to get ActionScript 3 to work with Google adWords?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-ads-api

I have some banner ads in AS3 that I need to make work with Google adWords. I am told AS3 is not supported and there are no immediate plans to.... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to my wordpress blog to see how I created a workaround. Although google does not directly support AS3, there is a way to use AS3 content as long as you stay within their guidelines.

It is not an officially sanctioned solution, but for now it works well. I have used it for over a year now.

http://exoboy.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/google-adwords-actionscript-3-and-me/